# How to execute a second bash command if output of first bash command outputs zero lines?

Tags: bash

I want to create a crontab entry for it.
So the solution has to be a one liner as I do not want to write a script and then invoke that script in crontab (with full if else inside a script-file, I can do this easily).

But I want to use some `&&` or `||` to achieve something like:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | wc -l != 0? mail -s "Found xyz"  ...
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Yes: store the script in `/usr/local/bin` and execute it from `cron`.

Comment: I don't want to that. Is it possible by just using the && || operators, like directly mentioning it in the crontab. I don't want to put the script in a file. With that, I can do the whole bash scripting there but I don't want to use a script-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
test "$(unreadable | long | list | of | commands | in | one | line)" && mail -s ...
```

It is useless to count the lines, if you just want to know, if the commands produce any output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | grep '^' >/dev/null && mail -s "Found xyz"
```

With `&&`, it'll run the final command (`mail`) if there's at least one line of output. If you want to send mail if there *isn't* any output, use `||` instead.

Explanation: the `grep` command succeeds if it finds any lines matching the given pattern. The pattern `^` matches the beginning of a line... any line. So `grep '^'` succeeds if there's at least one line (even a blank one). The `>/dev/null` then discards the output.

(You could also use `grep -q` instead of the `>/dev/null`, but then `grep` will exit after the first match, which may cause SIGPIPE errors for the earlier commands, and possibly weird problems. I consider the `>/dev/null` method safer when used in a pipeline.)